# UITapGestureRecognizer blocks touch event for UIButton in subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I believe I have an issue with UITapGestureRecognizer for dismissing keyboard when tapping in chatroom area preventing or blocking touch to the previewCancelButton. Here below are my relevant codes:

***BaseTemplateVC.m***

```
- (void)addDismissKeyboardGesture {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    self.view.tag = 111;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void) dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = sender;
    UIView *view = gesture.view;
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)view.tag);
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

***ChatroomVC.m***

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{

    //Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the segmented control.
    if (([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])) {
        NSLog(@"noooooooo");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
    NSLog(@"yesssssss"); 
}
```

***InputFunctionView.m***

```
- (void)selectedSticker:(NSString *)stickerURLString {

    /* Sticker preview subview */
    stickerPreviewView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -120, FrameWidth, 120)];
    stickerPreviewView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
    stickerPreviewView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:stickerPreviewView];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:stickerPreviewView];

    /* Initialise previewCancelButton */
    self.previewCancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.previewCancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(Main_Screen_Width-30, SpaceForItems-120, 20, 20);
    [self.previewCancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_previewcancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.previewCancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_previewcancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [self.previewCancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview: self.previewCancelButton];

}

/* Cancel sticker preview subview */
- (void)cancelStickerPreviewButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"cancel sticker preview");
    [self.previewCancelButton removeFromSuperview];
    [stickerPreviewView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Now the previewCancelButton is correctly on right top corner of stickerPreviewView but unable to receive touch event to it. When I touch the button it shows "111" in the console and when I traced back I found BaseTemplateVC.m that contains addDismissKeyboardGesture method, so I believe this may cause the issue.

Anyone can guide me to some solutions. That'd be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.[image]

**Progress:** I have modified gestureRecognizer method in ChatroomVC.m so now it can ignore tap gesture on the button but the problem remains action for the button doesn't get fired.

Comment: You can check the tap area in the gesture action function and programatically press the button with `.sendAction` and return rightaway if it's in the button area

Comment: @Tj3n I'm not sure how to check tap area for the button. Can you show me in code so I can understand exactly what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: can you please check clips to bound to yes and see that is your button still visible

Comment: @MikeAlter I tried `stickerPreviewView.clipsToBounds = YES;` and `self.previewCancelButton.clipsToBounds = YES;` and the button is still visible.

Comment: `self.clipsToBounds = YES` and see

Comment: @MikeAlter ok once I tried `self.clipsToBounds = YES;` the sticker view doesn't response to my tap so it can't bring up stickerPreview view.

Comment: you are trying to say that it is not visible right ?

Comment: @MikeAlter I mean stickerPreviewView + cancelPreviewButton can't be brought up because now the sticker view below doesn't response to tap.

Comment: it indicates that your sticker view might be out of bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this by using below code in GestureRecogniser delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
  if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:IFView.stickerPreviewView]) {
     return NO;
  }
     return YES;
}
```

It specifies exactly what subview in this case IFView.stickerPreviewView is to return NO. Also in InputFunctionView, use this instead to add the subview:

```
[self.superview addSubview:_stickerPreviewView];
```

Answer (score 7):

Just take a try with this, i guess it will work.
Use the `shouldReceiveTouch` delegate method of gesture, and **return NO** when the **touch.view** is button class.
So when it finds button It will discard the gesture and take button action.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    // Block the recognition of tap gestures in the button.
    if (([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])) {
       return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Here is the demo implementation :**
I have taken the button on main view of view controller in the story board.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureClicked:)];
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    // Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the segmented control.
    if (([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
- (IBAction)btnTestClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"test button click");
}

- (void)tapGestureClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recog
{
    NSLog(@"tap gesture clicked");
}
```

Hope it helps.
Happy coding ...

Comment: I actually don't want to discard original gesture but just to add touch recognition for the previewCancelButton in stickerPreviewView subview.

Comment: It will do like you want. When you click button it will return no to gesture, which results the gesture action won't not get fired and so button action fired. When you other than button inside the gesture area, it will call gesture method.

Comment: So where should I place your code into my existing code? Please bear with me; I'm very beginner. Thank you.

Comment: Check I have edited my answer with a demo implementation. 
You need to put the delegate in which view or ViewController, you are facing issue of gesture and button action collision.

Comment: Can you show your code? 
By the way did you put break point and check whether the cursor is coming  to the shouldReceiveTouch method or not?

Comment: I basically just added your shouldReceiveTouch method into my BaseTemplateVC.m and I don't see it's ever got called. I must have terribly missed something.

Comment: did you extend the delegate in your VC like @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>??

Comment: It turned out there's another view ChatroomVC that contains gestureRecognizer method and it inherited from BaseTemplateVC, so it overrides what I've done to gestureRecognizer. Now the problem remains the button doesn't get fired when touched.

Comment: Now I click the button it will return No to gesture but button action won't get fired still. Do you have any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: Write the same condition in child class, where you need it, as you are dong it in the base class and later the child class override that would be creating issue

Comment: That's what I mean. I already did that in child class which is ChatroomVC, so now it will return No to gesture but button action won't get fired still. Your code alone doesn't solve the whole thing yet.